# What's the difference between spawn here and spawn -->

Tags: jaseci

When spawning a walker in JAC, I noticed two seperate methods,
either `spawn here walker::walker_name;` and `spawn --> walker::walker_name;`

What are the differences between this two methods?

I tried the following code and noticed that the first one `test1` produced NULL type and `test2` produced an empty list `[]`

```
walker mytest {
    std.out("hello world");
}

walker init{
    root {
        test1 = spawn here walker::mytest;
        test2 = spawn --> walker::mytest;
        std.out(test1);
        std.out(test2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example `-->` represents a list of all nodes connected to the root node with a `-->` edge and `here` represents the root itself.

Also, in order to get a "return" variable from a walk, you have to use anchor has variables in the walker As per:

```
walker mytest {
    has anchor val = 7;
    std.out("hello world");
}
```

Then in

```
test1 = spawn here walker::mytest;
```

`test1` will equal 7.

Comment: The root node is connected to itself; why doesn't `spawn --> walker::mytest` execute on itself before walking to the other nodes? Is there a way to write it such that it executes the walker on the calling node before walking to the connected nodes?

Answer (score 0):

So `-->` is the list of nodes that are connected to the current node. `spawn --> walker::mytest` will spawn walkers on all nodes that are connected to the current node, which in case there aren't any. `spawn here` spawn the walker on the current node.